# How can we create timer job for SharePoint hosted apps?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, custom-timer-job, apps-development

"It is possible to create timer job for a SharePoint hosted app ".

If yes then I need detail information how we can achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

As a short answer: **No,** it's not possible,

---

**Instead,** you can implement a timer job on a provider-hosted application by creating a  `task scheduler` to run a console application.

**In this case,**

- **The SharePoint APP** will handle the authentication and assigns permissions required to connect and access the SharePoint site.
- **The Console application** will contain the logic that needs to be executed as per schedule.

---

**To achieve this workaround, check**

- [Step by step approach to create Timer Job Using SharePoint Apps](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/872556/Step-by-step-approach-to-create-Timer-Job-Using-Sh)
- [Building a SharePoint App as a Timer Job.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2014/03/02/building-a-sharepoint-app-as-a-timer-job/)
- [SharePoint 2013 Provider Hosted App Timer Job (Schedule Job)](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/3ad1bb/sharepoint-2013-provider-hosted-app-timer-job-schedule-job/)